# Submit multiple checkboxes to PHP

Tags: php, sql, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to submit multiple checkboxes to PHP in POST method. Each selected item should return a simple SQL query, here's my code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="synco[]" value="email" checked="checked" /> Sync email
<input type="checkbox" name="synco[]" value="birthday" checked="checked" /> Sync birthday
<input type="checkbox" name="synco[]" value="gender" checked="checked" /> Sync gender
<input type="checkbox" name="synco[]" value="bio" checked="checked" /> Sync bio
<input type="checkbox" name="synco[]" value="website" checked="checked" /> Sync website
```

**PHP:**

```
  $synco = $_POST['synco'];
  if(empty($synco))
  {
// Empty selection Error
  }
  else
  {
foreach($synco as $item) {

if ($synco == birthday) {
$item = $birthday;
$updaterow = birthday;
}
elseif ($synco == email) {
$item = $user_profile[email];
$updaterow = email_address;
}
elseif ($synco == gender) {
$item = $gender;
$updaterow = gender;
}
elseif ($synco == website) {
$item = $user_profile[website];
$updaterow = website;
}
else {
$item = $user_profile[bio];
$updaterow = bio;
}
                $mmhclass->db->query("UPDATE `table1` SET `[1]` = '[2]' WHERE `user_id` = '[3]';", array($updaterow, $item, $user_profile['id']));

// JSON Message

}
```

**Problem is:** when I submit my form, the sql updates only 1 item no matter how many inputs are checked.

Comment: You will probably need a loop.

Comment: @SamiDzHamida — Like `foreach($synco as $item) {`?

Comment: @SamiDzHamida He already is in a loop.. Just using the wrong condition

Comment: Yes, I realized. Lol.

Comment: Did not understand ,what you trying to do, I haven't seen this kind of query before `$mmhclass->db->query("UPDATE `table1` SET `[1]` = '[2]' WHERE `user_id` = '[3]';", array($updaterow, $item, $user_profile['id']));`

Comment: No need for downvote, the problem is not with the query though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if ($synco == birthday) {
```

try this

```
if ($item == birthday) {
```

You are in foreach loop for each $synco it is assumed as $item,so you need to check with the $item only

Comment: I already tried this before asking here, it didn't work. Makes more sense though.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($synco as $item) {

  if ($synco == birthday) {
    $item = $birthday;
    $updaterow = birthday;
  }
  elseif ($synco == email) {
    $item = $user_profile[email];
    $updaterow = email_address;
  }
  elseif ($synco == gender) {
    $item = $gender;
    $updaterow = gender;
  }
  elseif ($synco == website) {
    $item = $user_profile[website];
    $updaterow = website;
  }
```

You should be using `$item` instead of `$synco` further more.. If you have pre-defined constants under the name(s) of: birthday, email, gener, website... then disregard this:

You should be wrapping within quotes

eg:

```
if ($item == "birthday"){

}
```

Try using an alternative style for your query:

Original:

```
  $mmhclass->db->query("UPDATE `table1` SET `[1]` = '[2]' WHERE `user_id` = '[3]';", array($updaterow, $item, $user_profile['id']));
```

Way I'd approach:

```
$mmhclass->db->query("UPDATE `table1` SET `".$updaterow."`= '".$item."' WHERE `user_id`= '".$user_profile['id']."'");
```

Or use a prepared statement:

```
$Query = $mmhclass->db->prepare("UPDATE `table1` SET ?=? WHERE user_id=?");
$Query->bind_param('ssi',$updaterow,$item,$user_profile['id']);
$Query->execute();
$Query->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did that but it didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: @MacGyver What Database API you using?  MySQLPDO or MySQli?